# Programmatically Edit *.vdproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, project, markup

I have a Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project for deploying my software. Visual Studio does not seem to provide a way to link the version number of your software to the version number of your installer, among other things.

How can I programmatically change values, like `ProductVersion`, in `ProjectInstaller.vdproj` using C#? It doesn't look like a markup language I recognize, like XML or JSON.

Comment: i think MS does not support vdproj anymore.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-facts-on-visual-studio-setup-projects-45e66fe86d8d The earlier you migrate to some other tools such as WiX, the better. What you wanted can be easily done there.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [VDProjectXml](https://github.com/dump247/VDProjectXml).